# Boolean not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, and still trying to learn. I am getting the bool not callable error, can someone help me. I am completely confused on how to solve this issue.

```
def is_equal(num1,num2):
    return bool (num1 == num2)

e = is_equal(2,2)

if e == True():
    print("Is equal")

else:
    print("Not equal")
```

Answer (score 3):

True is actually boolean value not a callable function:

```
def is_equal(num1,num2):
    return bool (num1 == num2)

e = is_equal(2,2)

if e == True:
    print("Is equal")
else:
    print("Not equal")
```

Even shorthand is `if e:`

```
def is_equal(num1,num2):
    return bool (num1 == num2)

e = is_equal(2,2)

if e:
    print("Is equal")
else:
    print("Not equal")
```

As @ShadowRanger mentioned you don't need to explicitly convert the result to bool:

```
def is_equal(num1,num2):
    return num1 == num2
```

Comment: Also, `is_equal` should probably just be `return num1 == num2`; wrapping it in `bool` is unnecessary and (surprisingly) expensive (for built-in types, the `bool` wrapping that doesn't actually change the return value at all is typically more expensive than the actual equality comparison). There are some types (database model classes, `numpy` arrays) where `==` doesn't return `True` or `False`, but coercing them to `bool` just hides errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_equal(num1,num2): return bool (num1 == num2)

e = is_equal(2,2)

if e == True(): print("Is equal")

else: print("Not equal")
```

After 'True', you can't add '()'.'True' is a Boolean variate.